# How to make the following replacement?

Tags: replacement, symbolic, rule

Consider the following symbolic expression:

```
expr=mon[m,b]*kd[m,d]+band[a,c]alc[b,c]kd[a,d]+func[a,c]dum[a,c]kd[b,d] + f1[b,c]f2[d,c]
```

It has three types of summands: the ones where arguments of `kd` are included in the pre-factor, the ones where it is not, and those do not containing `kd`. I want to obtain

```
expr1=mon[d,b] + band[d,c]alc[b,c] + func[a,c]dum[a,c]kd[b,d] + f1[b,c]f2[d,c]
```

i.e. "contract" `kd` with the pre-factors. I may do this for the first two summands using the replacement

```
e_*kd[x_, y_] :> (e /. x -> y)
```

However, if applying to the third summand, it obviously removes `kd` and returns a wrong expression. In reality, I have a complicated expression generated in-flight, including the two types of summands, so I need a universal rule that does not touch the terms of the second type and replaces the terms of the first type.

What can be such a replacement rule?

Comment: What comprises a prefactor here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly check for the presence of arguments with [`ContainsAny`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAny.html).

```
expr /. e_[args__]*kd[x_, y_] /; 
   ContainsAny[{args}, {x, y}] :> (e[args] /. x -> y)
(* alc[b, c] band[d, c] + f1[b, c] f2[d, c] + 
   dum[a, c] func[a, c] kd[b, d] + mon[d, b] *)
```